How to I create a distinct list of child elements using XLS 1.0
Belows is the sample XML I have to work with.
<item type="food">
    <entities>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="BAN">banana</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="APP">apple</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="ORA">orange</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="LEM">lemon</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="GRA">grape</entity>
        <entity type="citrus" abbreviatedText="CIT">citrus             
            <entities>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="ORA">orange</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="LEM">lemon</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="LIM">lime</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="MAN">mandarin</entity>
            </entities>
        </entity>
    </entities>
</item>

I need to construct an XSL transformation that provides me with a distinct list of "fruits" from the initial set of entities, i.e. banana, apple, orange, lemon and grape, combined with the "citrus" group, i.e. orange, lemon, lime and mandarin.
There are 2 sets of records that will make up the distinct list. i.e.
/entities and
/entities/entity/entities
The resultant list should be a distinct list of fruits "abbreviatedText" attribute, in alphabetical order,  i.e.
APP, BAN, GRA, LEM, LIM, MAN, ORA.
i.e. any duplicates in the list should not show twice.
Output of text or HTML ok, gaol is to get the distinct values.
My limitations, at this stage are I have to work within XSL 1.0. I understand that XSL 1.0 is limited, I might have the option of XSL 2.0 or 3.0, if I can solve this with XSL 1.0 then it will be much easier.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried Googling several different answers, but nothing seems to provide the direction I needed.
UPDATE
I have been able to answer my own question with the direction of some of the comments.  As my question has an answer already associated with it, I thought I would add my resolution.
Below is a more detailed XML sample I'm working with.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item type="food">
    <entities>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="BAN">banana</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="APP">apple</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="ORA">orange</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="LEM">lemon</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="GRA">grape</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="STR">strawberry</entity>
        <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="WTR">water melon</entity>
        <entity type="other" abbreviatedText="CIT">citrus             
            <entities>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="ORA">orange</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="MAN">mandarin</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="LEM">lemon</entity>              
            </entities>
        </entity>
        <entity type="other" abbreviatedText="BRY">berry             
            <entities>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="GRA">grape</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="STR">strawberry</entity>
            </entities>
        </entity>
        <entity type="other" abbreviatedText="MEL">melon             
            <entities>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="WTR">water melon</entity>
                <entity type="fruit" abbreviatedText="RKM">rock melon</entity>
            </entities>
        </entity>
    </entities>
</item>

Here is my XSL that seems to work as expected.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="index_key" match="entity" use="@abbreviatedText" />
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="entities/entity[@type='fruit'][count(. | key('index_key', @abbreviatedText)[1]) = 1] | entities/entity[@type='other' and (@abbreviatedText='CIT' or @abbreviatedText='BRY')]/entities/entity[count(. | key('index_key', @abbreviatedText)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@abbreviatedText" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@abbreviatedText" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



The output will be:
APP
BAN
GRA
LEM
MAN
ORA
STR
WTR


The XSL has the flexibility to specify what entities are used.
Thanks to those who commented.

Check if your processor supports the set:distinct extension function. If not, use Muenchian grouping as suggested.

Note that abbriviatedText is not the same as abbreviatedText.

Thanks @y.arazim, type with "abbreviatedText" fixed. I will review the Muenchian method.

@tphallett Which XSLT processor are you using?

@michael.hor257k my understanding is that it is MSXML, I believe it was a version that was shipped with an old IE version.

Then Muenchian grouping (the first part of) is the best solution for you.
